# Sync data when has network flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, networking

I have a `ListView` in my app. When there is a new incoming message, the new list item will be highlighted (just like how Gmail works). When the new item in the list is tapped, it will pass the list item id to server and server will return the `hasRead == true` to indicate the list item has been read, then the list item will no longer be highlighted.

**Question**

I was able to achieve that if my app is connected to network. But how about if there is no network connection ? How should I know that the item in the list has been tapped, so  that when there is a network connection again it can send the item id to the server and update the UI by removing the highlight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by **caching** your user's action.

First you store the variable on a local db: sembast, sqlite or sharedpreference (whatever you like the best). You can see [my answer regarding sharedpreference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66426801/flutter-keeping-variables-value-after-each-app-restart/66426999#66426999).

Then you have a function that, whenever there is a new active connection to your network, will iterate over items that have been cached but not yet sent, and you will send them. You will have to check the return value of your server, that items have been properly sent.